# Discord.js Add / Remove role in 1 command

Tags: discord.js

**V12 Code**

I want to make this command can be used by anyone having a specific role or manage channel perm but it not works, it only allows people having manage channel perm not the people having specific role.

*Problem Code*

```js
if (!message.member.roles.cache.has('845453361008476190') || !message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_CHANNELS')) return message.channel.send("sorry, you do not have permission to use command.")
```

**Complete Code**

```js
const prefix = process.env.PREFIX;
module.exports = {
  name: 'vip',
  category: 'moderation',
  aliases: ['v'],
  description : 'Used give VIP to a User ',
  usage: `${prefix}vip <@user>`,
  run : async(client, message, args) => {
    if (!message.member.roles.cache.has('845453361008476190') || !message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_CHANNELS')) return message.channel.send("sorry, you do not have permission to use command.")
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("842019142118014996");
    const role = guild.roles.cache.get("845453369564856361");
    const aUser = message.mentions.users.first(); 
    if (!aUser) return message.channel.send("Can't find user!");
    const member = await guild.members.fetch(aUser.id);
    if (member.roles.cache.get(role.id)) {
      return (
        member.roles.remove(role),
        message.channel.send(`Removed VIP role from ${aUser.tag}`)
      );
    } else {
      await member.roles.add(role),
      message.channel.send(`${aUser.tag} Sucessfully got VIP role.`);
    }
  } 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This checks if the user doesn't have the required role, or doesn't have the required perms. Change the OR operator (`||`) to an AND operator (`&&`) so that if checks if the user doesn't have the required role, and doesn't have the required perms, return early

```js
if (!message.member.roles.cache.has('845453361008476190') && !message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_CHANNELS'))
```